# Is it possible to routes from spring xml and java dsl in camel?

Tags: apache-camel

The main routes are in spring, but sometimes java dsl is easier to prototype and run POC.

Is there a way to mix both or add java dsl route to the context from spring xml ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. Routes are discovered automatically by the rule set.
More information can be found here: http://camel.apache.org/spring.html

You can watch the following topics:

- Using Java Code
- Using package
- Using packageScan
- Using contextScan

Answer (score 0):

Yes . you can always do that . You can always use both ways of defining camel routes and mix them according to your need. See the link below for more information :

http://camel.apache.org/routes.html